# Parsing Google Places API with Ruby JSON Gem

Tags: ruby, json

Firstly just a big Thanks to everyone on this site, I am using it daily and learning loads! However I have become a little stuck on a problem.

What I am trying to do is to Parse the Google Places API into my own array format. I am using JSON to do this. If I use the below command on the command prompt I can get the right response: (i have changed a few things for privacy)

```
curl -e http://www.yoursire.com 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=51.50401607915134,-0.10931970886235831&radius=500&types=food&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCj58SthZHL75a5asdadsNCtbB6fdDe8'
```

If I then take this idea into ruby I have tried a few different things to grab the data. Firstly I have tried to do the following

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'

result = open("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=51.50401607915134,-0.10931970886235831&radius=500&types=food&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCj58SthZHLsdfsdf5sY0sNCtbB6fdDe8'").read

puts result
```

I get a hash error that looks like this:

```
{ "html_attributions" : [ ],"results" : [ ], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }
```

I am running this locally, which may be an issue, because the of `curl -e`, but I always get an error

The second option I have been trying is this:

```
require 'ruby-gems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

result = JSON.parse(open("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?location=51.50401607915134,-0.10931970886235831&radius=500&types=food&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCj58SthZHL75a5RQd5sY0sNCtbB6fdDe8").read)

puts result
```

Now I can't even get this one to run as i get the error:

```
./json.rb:5: undefined method `search' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from places.rb:3
```

So I cant even seem to get the JSON gem to work? I am trying to run this locally in code, make it work then port the idea over to the web using Rails, but I want to know exactly how it works (learning etc...) I think I know what to do with the data once I have it, but getting it and storing it seems a little problematic at the moment for me. I would appreciate any help any one can give me... even if its a "READ THIS".

Please note I am only using `puts result` at the end as a test to see if it works!

Thanks

Charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from the include line. Are you sure you've got the correct JSON gem for your Ruby installation? Try deleting all the code and just `require 'json'`. If you still get the error (and I think you will) then that's your problem.

For the actual JSON parsing line, I'd recommend doing it like this - it's cleaner and more idiomatic:

```
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?location=51.50401607915134,-0.10931970886235831&radius=500&types=food&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCj58SthZHL75a5RQd5sY0sNCtbB6fdDe8'
result = open(url) do |file|
  JSON.parse(file.read)
end
```

Comment: I left in 'require rubygems require json' and i get the errror
''./json.rb:5: undefined method `search' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
 from places.rb:2
''

Comment: I'd suggest you ask a separate question, because the problem you're having doesn't really match the question description. If you ask a new one you'll be more likely to get a decent answer. I'm not sure if I can help you any more with this error!

Answer (score 0):

For future readers: check this super simple client ([Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) based): https://gist.github.com/joost/e149404f645f33ba1939